# Fatal error: Call to a member function assistance required

Tags: php, mysql

I have taken over a website to complete.

The website works fine.

for some reason I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function navigate() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\studio.php on line 224

This is the code for the page at line 224:

```
if(!empty($_GET['nav']))
{
   $params = null;
   $params['listOrder'] = 'id desc';
   $$_GET['nav']->navigate($params); <<<This is line 224
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will you try $obj = $_GET['nav'];  $obj->navigate($params);

Comment: I doubt `$_GET['nav']` contains a valid object.

Comment: @Salim I tried that. Still does not work. It was working this morning and now it doesnt work anymore. I have no idea what changed.

Comment: May be $_GET['nav'] is not valid object. from where you are sending $_GET['nav'] need to check there.

Comment: I have now established that the parameter $params is the culprit. Is there a way to find out where it is called from. the site contains 4500 pages in 362 directories. Thank you for the assistance so far

Answer (score 0):

$$_GET['nav'] refers to an object dynamically, this object is not instanciated at the point of calling navigate(), or the variable passed to $_GET['nav'] does not correspond to a defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved. after a strenuous search I found a phantom piece of code that was where it should not have been. Thank you all for your assistance. The code was:

```
$user = $_SESSION['usr'];
```